# Возможно ли создать exe-файл, который будет работать без компилятора и библиотек?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, exe

Возможно ли создать на `qt` такой `exe`, что, скажем,  тащу я его в колледж на экзамен, при этом не взяв с собой ни компилятор, ни библиотеки,  вот прям ничего-ничего, только папку с картинками?

Причина - я там начудила с компилятором, у меня там стоит `libcurl`, кто знает,  что это, поймёт, как его запарно ставить, стоит `openssl`, да и сам QT весит прилично, ещё и спираченный, не хотелось бы такое носить с собой, вот бы просто экзешку принести, чтобы никто никакой внутрянки (кроме кода) не видел. Реально ли это?

Comment: Да, вам нужна статическая сборка. Нужно самостоятельно скомпилировать Qt и openssl в виде статической библиотеки и прилинковать их к вашему файлу.

Comment: Спасибо, прочитаю про такую

Comment: Почему не хочется брать компилятор - я понимаю. А почему не хочется брать библиотеки? Ну будет у вас папка с .dll-ками - это нормально. Самому никакие библиотеки компилировать не надо. Надо воспользоваться `winqtdeploy` - он вам сделает папку со всеми нужными .dll.

Comment: Любопытно зачем пиратить Qt? Он же бесплатный.

Comment: Мне даже больше интересно не зачем, а как)